# Real-time MySQL monitoring

Tags: php, mysql, real-time

I was wondering if there is a tool that I can monitor MySQL DB data in real time using PHP?

Currently I use an Ajax call to check the database for any updates every few seconds but I assume this is not the correct way when I have more users as it puts a lot of pressure on the server.

** Just to add a note that I actually want to show the data on my website which is written based on PHP, so it would be useful to find out what is the best way to integrate other tools in order to achieve this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

PHP is not really the best for real time monitoring as it is (normally) transaction based (HTTP).

There is a free open source Java program called "Mysql Monitor Tool" which can monitor a MySQL (or multiple) databases in real time:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysqlmt/

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Thank you very much, is there any program (Java or other languages) that I can install on my server and then interact with my website which is developed using PHP to show the real-time data?

Comment: @SwissChocolate PHPMyAdmin has statistics

Answer (score 2):

I use JET Profiler: http://www.jetprofiler.com/

it has a free version too.

Comment: Thank you but I would like to show the data on my website, this looks like an application

Comment: Oh, in that case. I either read out the transaction log every x seconds or just make my own logging where I insert every performed SQL statement in a table (with a start and end time), and upon finish I'd also log the number of affected rows. Then on the PHP side, I'd do a 'select top 50' of that table and refresh every x seconds via Ajax.

It's not a perfect technique but it's just doing a top 50 select statement on your SQL server, which isn't that time/memory consuming

Answer (score 1):

Mysql Workbench has a server monitoring feature as well. It shows basically most things you need to know in real time.

To open it, open a connection with a DB, click on the "Server" tab and then "Server Status".

Answer (score 0):

after long searching I found a new free one http://www.profilesql.com/

great tool, it makes a proxy between app and db